# Usando resample no pandas com variável de data intermitente

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho uma base de dados em que uma coluna é o ano e as demais colunas são o total de trabalhadores formais em uma cidade (cada coluna uma cidade). Meu objetivo é simplesmente agregar meus dados anuais para trienais. Segue um exemplo replicável com o que fiz até agora:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Ano': range(1890,1920),
'A': [random.choice(range(0,50)) for k in range(0,30)],
'B': [random.choice(range(0,50)) for k in range(0,30)],
'C': [random.choice(range(0,50)) for k in range(0,30)]},
index=range(0,30))
#tiro um ano de propósito para replicar o fato de que minha base não tem informação para todos os anos
df = df[df['Ano']!=1907]

df['Ano'] = [datetime.strptime(str(k), '%Y') for k in df['Ano']]

df.set_index('Ano', inplace=True)
print(df.resample('3T').sum())
```

Problema:

- O `3T` eu usei com base no que vi na documentação do [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), mas
  creio que não interpretei isso corretamente já que esse comando está
  rodando durante muito tempo até travar meu computador.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver aqui. Qual o procedimento correto nesse caso, postar a resposta para que outros usuários possam ver ou apagar a pergunta?

Comment: Se você tiver boa vontade de ajudar, postar a resposta é melhor!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, a solução era simplesmente fazer:

```
print(df.resample('3A').sum())
```

Dentro da documentação que citei na pergunta, havia um [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects) em uma nota contendo a tabela abaixo de *offset_string*. Então, você só precisa identificar a unidade de tempo que está sua variável de data e efetuar o **downsample** utilizando o número correspondente ao novo período. No meu caso, passei de anual ("A") para trienal ("3A"). Outros casos são análogos. Segue a tabela para referência:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em relação ao fato da série ser intermitente, optei por criar os anos faltantes e preencher os valores nas colunas iguais a zero e,só então, realizar a agregação.

**EDIT:** Uma solução menos manual e mais elegante para lhe dar com séries com datas intermitentes foi dada na resposta do [@lmonferrari](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/201329/lmonferrari) nessa questão: [Existe alguma forma de o pd.Grouper, quanto usado para frequências temporais, adicionar linhas mesmo quando não há registros em um intervalo de tempo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/486916/existe-alguma-forma-de-o-pd-grouper-quanto-usado-para-frequ%c3%aancias-temporais-ad/486964#486964)