# Existe alguma forma de o pd.Grouper, quanto usado para frequências temporais, adicionar linhas mesmo quando não há registros em um intervalo de tempo?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Preciso fazer merge entre duas tabelas em que a tabela base esta agrupada em intervalos de 5 minutos, entretanto em um intervalo que não tem nenhum registro a ser agrupado a linha correspondente não é criada

Estou lidando com dados de radar em São Paulo e, por exemplo, nos intervalos da madrugada, tem menos passagem de carros, e muitas vezes não passa nenhum, de forma que no agrupamento esse registro de "vazio" não aparece ;(

```
df_agregado = df_agregado.groupby([ 'Numero Agrupado',pd.Grouper(key='Data', freq='5Min')]).agg({ Registro": "count",Velocidade': 'mean'})
```

Resultado esperado:

```
                       Registro   Velocidade
2018-01-03 00:00:00         nan          nan           
2018-01-03 08:05:00         nan          nan           
2018-01-03 08:10:00         nan          nan           
2018-01-03 08:15:00           5           22   
2018-01-03 08:20:00          10           31
2018-01-03 08:25:00         nan          nan
```

Resultado obtido:

```
                       Registro   Velocidade
2018-01-03 08:15:00           5           22   
2018-01-03 08:20:00          10           31
```

O dataset para teste está disponível [aqui](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1vBa1AgR-8_6fseag_8vPz-xPq9XgFrcj?usp=sharing) para o Dataframe antes e depois do agrupamento

**obs.:**
Observe que entre 01h50 e 2h00 não há o registro de 1h55

Comment: Pode disponibilizar um dataset de exemplo para que a gente possa replicar seu problema?

Comment: acabei de disponibilizar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `asfreq` do `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('./Antes do Agrupamento.csv', parse_dates=['Data'])
df_agregado = df.groupby(['Numero Agrupado', pd.Grouper(key='Data', freq='5 min')]).agg({ "Registro": "count","Velocidade": 'mean'}).reset_index()

df_agregado.set_index('Data').asfreq('5 min').reset_index()
```

1. Importando o pacote pandas
2. Carregando o arquivo de dados
3. Fazendo a agregação
4. Data frame com frequência de 5 minutos

Saída:

```
          Data          Numero Agrupado    Registro Velocidade
    2018-01-03 00:00:00        10680          10    115,4
    2018-01-03 00:05:00        10680          13    123,2307692
    2018-01-03 00:10:00        10680          10    119,2
    2018-01-03 00:15:00        10680          12    116,0833333
    2018-01-03 00:20:00        10680          13    111,7692308
    2018-01-03 00:25:00        10680          17    121,8823529
    2018-01-03 00:30:00        10680          10    126,5
    2018-01-03 00:35:00        10680           9    117
    2018-01-03 00:40:00        10680          11    109,2727273
    2018-01-03 00:45:00        10680          12    114,1666667
    2018-01-03 00:50:00        10680           7    124,5714286
    2018-01-03 00:55:00        10680           9    116,1111111
    2018-01-03 01:00:00        10680           3    124,3333333
    2018-01-03 01:05:00        10680          10    117,4
    2018-01-03 01:10:00        10680           5    120,4
    2018-01-03 01:15:00        10680           5    128,4
    2018-01-03 01:20:00        10680           5    117,2
    2018-01-03 01:25:00        10680           4    123,5
    2018-01-03 01:30:00        10680           2    104
    2018-01-03 01:35:00        10680           5    121,8
    2018-01-03 01:40:00        10680           3    121,3333333
    2018-01-03 01:45:00        10680           3    123
    2018-01-03 01:50:00        10680           4    110,25
    2018-01-03 01:55:00          NaN          NaN   NaN
    .....
```

Comment: Boa. Solução mais simples que a minha. Considere dar upvote na pergunta. Infelizmente, algum troll deu downvote em uma pergunta bem feita e relevante para o site. Recomendação de leitura: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente

Comment: @Lucas Eu sempre voto, a comunidade do 'Python' que não vota muito. A do R a galera vota com força.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é:

1. Criar um banco de dados vazio;
2. Colocar as datas nesse banco que pertencem ao intervalo desejado mas não tem informação;
3. Apensar com o banco original.

Segue código com essa solução:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
pd.set_option('max.rows',500) #printar mais linha para checar se cóigo funcionou

df = pd.read_csv("antes_agrup.csv").iloc[:,1:]
df['Data']=pd.to_datetime(df["Data"])

df_agg = df.groupby(['Numero Agrupado',pd.Grouper(key='Data', freq='5Min')]).agg({ "Registro": "count","Velocidade": 'mean'})
df_agg.reset_index(inplace=True)

dates = df_agg['Data'].to_list()
dates.sort()

all_ranges = pd.date_range(start=dates[0], end=dates[-1],freq='5Min')
empty_ranges=[k for k in all_ranges if k not in dates]
cols=df_agg.columns.to_list()
cols.remove("Data")
empty = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols, index = empty_ranges)

df_agg.set_index('Data',drop=True,inplace=True)

df_agg = df_agg.append(empty)
df_agg.sort_index(inplace=True)

print(df_agg.iloc[:500,:])
```

Retorna:

```
                   Numero Agrupado Registro  Velocidade
2018-01-03 00:00:00           10680       10  115.400000
2018-01-03 00:05:00           10680       13  123.230769
2018-01-03 00:10:00           10680       10  119.200000
2018-01-03 00:15:00           10680       12  116.083333
2018-01-03 00:20:00           10680       13  111.769231
2018-01-03 00:25:00           10680       17  121.882353
2018-01-03 00:30:00           10680       10  126.500000
2018-01-03 00:35:00           10680        9  117.000000
2018-01-03 00:40:00           10680       11  109.272727
2018-01-03 00:45:00           10680       12  114.166667
2018-01-03 00:50:00           10680        7  124.571429
2018-01-03 00:55:00           10680        9  116.111111
2018-01-03 01:00:00           10680        3  124.333333
2018-01-03 01:05:00           10680       10  117.400000
2018-01-03 01:10:00           10680        5  120.400000
2018-01-03 01:15:00           10680        5  128.400000
2018-01-03 01:20:00           10680        5  117.200000
2018-01-03 01:25:00           10680        4  123.500000
2018-01-03 01:30:00           10680        2  104.000000
2018-01-03 01:35:00           10680        5  121.800000
2018-01-03 01:40:00           10680        3  121.333333
2018-01-03 01:45:00           10680        3  123.000000
2018-01-03 01:50:00           10680        4  110.250000
2018-01-03 01:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-03 02:00:00           10680        2  107.000000
2018-01-03 02:05:00           10680        3  122.000000
2018-01-03 02:10:00           10680        5  137.200000
2018-01-03 02:15:00           10680        2   87.500000
2018-01-03 02:20:00           10680        3  101.000000
2018-01-03 02:25:00           10680        2  129.500000
2018-01-03 02:30:00           10680        2  187.500000
2018-01-03 02:35:00           10680        2  127.500000
2018-01-03 02:40:00           10680        2  117.000000
2018-01-03 02:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-03 02:50:00           10680        1  122.000000
2018-01-03 02:55:00           10680        2  118.000000
2018-01-03 03:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-03 03:05:00           10680        3  113.000000
2018-01-03 03:10:00           10680        1  131.000000
2018-01-03 03:15:00           10680        1  131.000000
2018-01-03 03:20:00           10680        1  128.000000
2018-01-03 03:25:00           10680        3  117.666667
2018-01-03 03:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-03 03:35:00           10680        2  122.000000
2018-01-03 03:40:00           10680        3  129.666667
2018-01-03 03:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-03 03:50:00           10680        1  119.000000
2018-01-03 03:55:00           10680        3  135.333333
2018-01-03 04:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-03 04:05:00           10680        3  113.000000
2018-01-03 04:10:00           10680        2  114.000000
2018-01-03 04:15:00           10680        1  108.000000
2018-01-03 04:20:00           10680        1  106.000000
2018-01-03 04:25:00           10680        3  126.000000
2018-01-03 04:30:00           10680        4  116.750000
2018-01-03 04:35:00           10680        3  120.000000
2018-01-03 04:40:00           10680        2  122.000000
2018-01-03 04:45:00           10680        4  118.000000
2018-01-03 04:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-03 04:55:00           10680        5  121.600000
2018-01-03 05:00:00           10680        3  113.000000
2018-01-03 05:05:00           10680        5   98.200000
2018-01-03 05:10:00           10680        7  119.857143
2018-01-03 05:15:00           10680        4  123.500000
2018-01-03 05:20:00           10680        8  109.250000
2018-01-03 05:25:00           10680        6  110.500000
2018-01-03 05:30:00           10680       15  113.600000
2018-01-03 05:35:00           10680        9  114.777778
2018-01-03 05:40:00           10680        4  109.000000
2018-01-03 05:45:00           10680       14  109.928571
2018-01-03 05:50:00           10680        9  118.444444
2018-01-03 05:55:00           10680        9  114.444444
2018-01-03 06:00:00           10680        9  112.888889
2018-01-03 06:05:00           10680       10  117.100000
2018-01-03 06:10:00           10680        9  112.333333
2018-01-03 06:15:00           10680       18  111.444444
2018-01-03 06:20:00           10680       10  116.300000
2018-01-03 06:25:00           10680       17  107.000000
2018-01-03 06:30:00           10680       15  111.466667
2018-01-03 06:35:00           10680       12  111.583333
2018-01-03 06:40:00           10680       16  110.250000
2018-01-03 06:45:00           10680        8  113.125000
2018-01-03 06:50:00           10680       14  113.000000
2018-01-03 06:55:00           10680       21  116.619048
2018-01-03 07:00:00           10680        9  123.777778
2018-01-03 07:05:00           10680       17  115.117647
2018-01-03 07:10:00           10680       11  118.636364
2018-01-03 07:15:00           10680       15  112.933333
2018-01-03 07:20:00           10680       21  114.904762
2018-01-03 07:25:00           10680       15  113.466667
2018-01-03 07:30:00           10680       14  110.785714
2018-01-03 07:35:00           10680       20  108.250000
2018-01-03 07:40:00           10680       15  115.266667
2018-01-03 07:45:00           10680       23  106.304348
2018-01-03 07:50:00           10680       15  113.733333
2018-01-03 07:55:00           10680       28  113.392857
2018-01-03 08:00:00           10680       11  120.181818
2018-01-03 08:05:00           10680       28  111.357143
2018-01-03 08:10:00           10680       21  115.523810
2018-01-03 08:15:00           10680       20  108.550000
2018-01-03 08:20:00           10680       25  107.440000
2018-01-03 08:25:00           10680       20  114.450000
2018-01-03 08:30:00           10680       25  104.480000
2018-01-03 08:35:00           10680       29  109.896552
2018-01-03 08:40:00           10680       19  101.526316
2018-01-03 08:45:00           10680       25  105.400000
2018-01-03 08:50:00           10680       25  113.680000
2018-01-03 08:55:00           10680       26  108.500000
2018-01-03 09:00:00           10680       26  108.038462
2018-01-03 09:05:00           10680       33  106.818182
2018-01-03 09:10:00           10680       19  110.052632
2018-01-03 09:15:00           10680       25  112.200000
2018-01-03 09:20:00           10680       28  114.178571
2018-01-03 09:25:00           10680       25  114.120000
2018-01-03 09:30:00           10680       27  110.481481
2018-01-03 09:35:00           10680       27  114.222222
2018-01-03 09:40:00           10680       26  107.461538
2018-01-03 09:45:00           10680       41  111.926829
2018-01-03 09:50:00           10680       36  104.944444
2018-01-03 09:55:00           10680       26  109.461538
2018-01-03 10:00:00           10680       34   95.500000
2018-01-03 10:05:00           10680       45  100.177778
2018-01-03 10:10:00           10680       45   93.800000
2018-01-03 10:15:00           10680       25   97.960000
2018-01-03 10:20:00           10680       37  100.756757
2018-01-03 10:25:00           10680       23  101.130435
2018-01-03 10:30:00           10680       28   97.607143
2018-01-03 10:35:00           10680       38  100.052632
2018-01-03 10:40:00           10680       19  106.736842
2018-01-03 10:45:00           10680       32   94.125000
2018-01-03 10:50:00           10680       36   79.222222
2018-01-03 10:55:00           10680       31   90.225806
2018-01-03 11:00:00           10680       29  101.931034
2018-01-03 11:05:00           10680       28   98.428571
2018-01-03 11:10:00           10680       20  100.500000
2018-01-03 11:15:00           10680       31  103.322581
2018-01-03 11:20:00           10680       25   92.000000
2018-01-03 11:25:00           10680       26  102.884615
2018-01-03 11:30:00           10680       35   98.742857
2018-01-03 11:35:00           10680       21   89.238095
2018-01-03 11:40:00           10680       35   89.571429
2018-01-03 11:45:00           10680       41   84.536585
2018-01-03 11:50:00           10680       35   58.800000
2018-01-03 11:55:00           10680       20   50.900000
2018-01-03 12:00:00           10680       32   88.718750
2018-01-03 12:05:00           10680       35   89.257143
2018-01-03 12:10:00           10680       48   67.666667
2018-01-03 12:15:00           10680       36   49.805556
2018-01-03 12:20:00           10680       30   79.533333
2018-01-03 12:25:00           10680       36  100.472222
2018-01-03 12:30:00           10680       36   98.083333
2018-01-03 12:35:00           10680       24   90.875000
2018-01-03 12:40:00           10680       28   93.892857
2018-01-03 12:45:00           10680       32   97.031250
2018-01-03 12:50:00           10680       35   82.400000
2018-01-03 12:55:00           10680       28   95.928571
2018-01-03 13:00:00           10680       34   88.323529
2018-01-03 13:05:00           10680       35   95.257143
2018-01-03 13:10:00           10680       25   89.840000
2018-01-03 13:15:00           10680       33   98.606061
2018-01-03 13:20:00           10680       22   42.772727
2018-01-03 13:25:00           10680       43   58.023256
2018-01-03 13:30:00           10680       29   81.275862
2018-01-03 13:35:00           10680       30   71.833333
2018-01-03 13:40:00           10680       27   51.074074
2018-01-03 13:45:00           10680       33   84.242424
2018-01-03 13:50:00           10680       24   52.375000
2018-01-03 13:55:00           10680       27   37.444444
2018-01-03 14:00:00           10680       27   41.222222
2018-01-03 14:05:00           10680       33   25.727273
2018-01-03 14:10:00           10680       30   35.333333
2018-01-03 14:15:00           10680       23   44.652174
2018-01-03 14:20:00           10680       32   31.343750
2018-01-03 14:25:00           10680       34   52.411765
2018-01-03 14:30:00           10680       41   63.756098
2018-01-03 14:35:00           10680       26   26.500000
2018-01-03 14:40:00           10680       33   38.181818
2018-01-03 14:45:00           10680       23   28.739130
2018-01-03 14:50:00           10680       20   27.500000
2018-01-03 14:55:00           10680       22   20.500000
2018-01-03 15:00:00           10680       31   40.967742
2018-01-03 15:05:00           10680       23   22.173913
2018-01-03 15:10:00           10680       12   35.250000
2018-01-03 15:15:00           10680       31   41.838710
2018-01-03 15:20:00           10680       28   52.714286
2018-01-03 15:25:00           10680       24   61.416667
2018-01-03 15:30:00           10680       20   32.800000
2018-01-03 15:35:00           10680       19   28.789474
2018-01-03 15:40:00           10680       27   26.296296
2018-01-03 15:45:00           10680       33   27.787879
2018-01-03 15:50:00           10680       24   38.416667
2018-01-03 15:55:00           10680       13   23.846154
2018-01-03 16:00:00           10680       25   31.360000
2018-01-03 16:05:00           10680       30   24.100000
2018-01-03 16:10:00           10680       26   67.461538
2018-01-03 16:15:00           10680       24   91.833333
2018-01-03 16:20:00           10680       23  112.608696
2018-01-03 16:25:00           10680       30  119.366667
2018-01-03 16:30:00           10680       29  110.655172
2018-01-03 16:35:00           10680       22  115.227273
2018-01-03 16:40:00           10680       27   94.777778
2018-01-03 16:45:00           10680       13  103.384615
2018-01-03 16:50:00           10680       17  104.352941
2018-01-03 16:55:00           10680       26  115.576923
2018-01-03 17:00:00           10680       18  116.222222
2018-01-03 17:05:00           10680       24  119.541667
2018-01-03 17:10:00           10680       21  114.666667
2018-01-03 17:15:00           10680       16  112.937500
2018-01-03 17:20:00           10680       17  104.882353
2018-01-03 17:25:00           10680       30  108.833333
2018-01-03 17:30:00           10680       17  116.705882
2018-01-03 17:35:00           10680       36  108.361111
2018-01-03 17:40:00           10680       25  111.360000
2018-01-03 17:45:00           10680       34  113.823529
2018-01-03 17:50:00           10680       27  105.111111
2018-01-03 17:55:00           10680       33  105.969697
2018-01-03 18:00:00           10680       33  106.242424
2018-01-03 18:05:00           10680       24  116.125000
2018-01-03 18:10:00           10680       21  109.047619
2018-01-03 18:15:00           10680       37   80.135135
2018-01-03 18:20:00           10680       26  102.769231
2018-01-03 18:25:00           10680       39   85.025641
2018-01-03 18:30:00           10680       33   92.090909
2018-01-03 18:35:00           10680       17  118.235294
2018-01-03 18:40:00           10680       24  111.833333
2018-01-03 18:45:00           10680       28  110.857143
2018-01-03 18:50:00           10680       29  110.241379
2018-01-03 18:55:00           10680       31  108.483871
2018-01-03 19:00:00           10680       30  107.466667
2018-01-03 19:05:00           10680       23  114.391304
2018-01-03 19:10:00           10680       31  101.290323
2018-01-03 19:15:00           10680       33   94.121212
2018-01-03 19:20:00           10680       37   91.540541
2018-01-03 19:25:00           10680       34   92.058824
2018-01-03 19:30:00           10680       29   95.655172
2018-01-03 19:35:00           10680       46   91.413043
2018-01-03 19:40:00           10680       23  108.304348
2018-01-03 19:45:00           10680       21  117.714286
2018-01-03 19:50:00           10680       24  114.750000
2018-01-03 19:55:00           10680       26  109.423077
2018-01-03 20:00:00           10680       29  109.241379
2018-01-03 20:05:00           10680       25  105.400000
2018-01-03 20:10:00           10680       26  115.384615
2018-01-03 20:15:00           10680       41   99.487805
2018-01-03 20:20:00           10680       20  101.550000
2018-01-03 20:25:00           10680       28   99.071429
2018-01-03 20:30:00           10680       21  103.428571
2018-01-03 20:35:00           10680       31   91.322581
2018-01-03 20:40:00           10680       22  104.409091
2018-01-03 20:45:00           10680       24   97.166667
2018-01-03 20:50:00           10680       26  103.384615
2018-01-03 20:55:00           10680       28  101.928571
2018-01-03 21:00:00           10680       16  105.375000
2018-01-03 21:05:00           10680       23  104.913043
2018-01-03 21:10:00           10680        9  125.000000
2018-01-03 21:15:00           10680       13  114.615385
2018-01-03 21:20:00           10680       21  104.761905
2018-01-03 21:25:00           10680       15  116.000000
2018-01-03 21:30:00           10680       13  117.000000
2018-01-03 21:35:00           10680       23  110.521739
2018-01-03 21:40:00           10680       17  103.470588
2018-01-03 21:45:00           10680       15  119.600000
2018-01-03 21:50:00           10680       13  115.923077
2018-01-03 21:55:00           10680       10  117.900000
2018-01-03 22:00:00           10680       13  110.384615
2018-01-03 22:05:00           10680       16  116.250000
2018-01-03 22:10:00           10680       18  110.777778
2018-01-03 22:15:00           10680       23  111.826087
2018-01-03 22:20:00           10680       18  128.222222
2018-01-03 22:25:00           10680       19  121.736842
2018-01-03 22:30:00           10680       20  112.650000
2018-01-03 22:35:00           10680       17  116.176471
2018-01-03 22:40:00           10680       10  119.500000
2018-01-03 22:45:00           10680       17  121.941176
2018-01-03 22:50:00           10680        7  107.000000
2018-01-03 22:55:00           10680       10  115.000000
2018-01-03 23:00:00           10680       16  123.187500
2018-01-03 23:05:00           10680       19  110.421053
2018-01-03 23:10:00           10680       14  125.785714
2018-01-03 23:15:00           10680       11  115.909091
2018-01-03 23:20:00           10680       23  114.782609
2018-01-03 23:25:00           10680       15  110.066667
2018-01-03 23:30:00           10680       10  112.100000
2018-01-03 23:35:00           10680       15  113.733333
2018-01-03 23:40:00           10680       14  123.642857
2018-01-03 23:45:00           10680        9  111.555556
2018-01-03 23:50:00           10680       16  119.937500
2018-01-03 23:55:00           10680        1  114.000000
2018-01-04 00:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 00:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 01:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 02:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 03:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 04:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 05:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 06:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 07:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 08:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 09:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:05:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:10:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:15:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:20:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:25:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:30:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:35:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:40:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:45:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:50:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 10:55:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
2018-01-04 11:00:00             NaN      NaN         NaN
```

Claro, você pode substituir os NaN por zero usando `df_agg.fillna(0)`